# How can get current field from form in Django UpdateView like cleaned_data.get('some_field') when use a function?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I need to take one field from the form, make calculations and insert the result into the second field. If you use a function, you can use cleaned _data.get ('first_field') for this, but how to do this using UpdateView?

Thank you!

Comment: you can do this by setting commit=False in your form eg. `a = form.save(commit=False)` than access any field like this `a.myfield = myvalue` and than save it `a.save()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want t odo it from the backend then preferring to do it as:

```
record = form.save(commit=False)
record.field1 = record.field2
record.save()
```

Otherwise, You need to do it from jQuery or JS before submitting the form.